# Stop getting Real Time update on Firebase Database Reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know firebase database is a real time database but for my feature I don't want to update a specific database reference (below reference) value in real time. So, is there any way to stop getting real time update on firebase database reference?

```
mUserDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you shared only creates a reference to a location in the database. It does not start getting realtime updates yet. To start getting realtime update, attach a listener with `addValueEventListener` or [`addChildEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events). An example of the latter:

```
ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
  }
};
mUserDataRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

This will receive data updates until the listener it removed. To [remove the listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#detach_listeners), call:

```
mUserDataRef.removeEventListener(childEventListener);
```

If you only want to get data once, instead of receiving continuous updates, you can call [`addListenerForSingleValueEvent`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once):

```
mUserDataRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
  }
});
```

I highly recommend studying these two pages in the Firebase documentation:

- [Read and write data on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)
- [Work with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)

Comment: thank you so much for helping me out. I actually did know how to get data from reference. I just wanted to get data update only for once and I applied addValueEventListenere(); so every times when data get changed, my event listener get updated. I didn't want that.. so adding addListenerForSingleValueEvent() the issues get resolved..Thanks again for helping me out! have a good day!

Comment: Good to hear this allowed you to solve the problem. For future question: always include what you've already tried. It makes it easier to help, since there's less guessing involved.

Comment: thank you so @Frank once again for the advice...I'll definitely keep that in mind!